# printing out x of x objects from an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

what's the best way to sort or query an array of objects with javascript? say I want to only get the first two objects, and then the next two, or get 5 starting from the 5th one?

what functions should I look at?

```html
var obj = [
  {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164802",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164805",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164806",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164807",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164808",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164809",
    "isActive": true
  },
    {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164810",
    "isActive": true
  }
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: What @Kinduser is gently suggesting is that you add to your post what you have already tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj.slice(0,2);//first two
obj.slice(2,4);//next two
```

And for rest do the math based on slice API.

Comment: @Agalo Yeah, please experiment or read the documentation. It doesn't mutate.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I confused with splice